# Does then() really return a promise in all cases?

Tags: javascript, promise

I was of the understanding that the `then()` promise method always itself returns a promise. Promises are something I'm still getting used to being a bit of a newb, so I've just been going over some examples and tinkering. The following example shows that the return value of the `then` method is an object.

```js
const foo = true;

const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (foo) {
            resolve('Do this');
        } else {
            reject(Error("Do that"));
        }
    }, 1500)
})

const bar = myPromise.then(value => value);

console.log(typeof bar); // object
```

Is this the same as returning a promise? Or do I need to explicitly tell `then` to return a promise like so (pseudocode, I know not correct) :

```js
.then(value => {
    // do something 
    return new Promise;
})
```

I want to make sure I've got this. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: you forget `.catch(function(error) {....`

Comment: Yes, `then` *always* returns a new promise for the result of the respective callback. *Iff* that callback returns a promise that one will be awaited as well, but if the callback returns a plain value (or even `undefined`) then the promise will simply fulfill with that.

Comment: using `await` -> ```const bar = await myPromise.then(value => value);
console.log(typeof bar); // string```

Comment: `typeof` won't tell you if something is a promise. It returns `"object"` for almost any kind of object, including promises. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 4):

Yes, The `then()` method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

And the promise is an object and the typeof promise will be an `object`. You don't need to explicit return a promise.

You can read more about the `promises` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah `then()` always return a promise. However, the pseudocode is incorrect. The function `then` takes two arguments:

```
p.then(onFulfilled[, onRejected]);

p.then(value => {
  // fulfillment
}, reason => {
  // rejection
});
```

Exactly like the `Promise` constructor. `Then` create a promise from another one. We often omit the `onRejected` argument because of we handle the reject case with `catch`.

Here an interesting article: https://medium.com/@kevinyckim33/what-are-promises-in-javascript-f1a5fc5b34bf

And the `then` doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: `then` creates a promise, what if returned value inside `then` is a promise
so `promise` is created by `then` whose resolved value is `promise` ??